# ethereum send transaction is not working?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, rinkeby

[image]I wrote a sample api to send ethers from one account to another account using rinkeby testnet.It's throwing the following error(I attached screenshot). Please tell me how to resolve that error and why this error is coming?[image]

Here is my code

```
app.post("/sendTransaction", async (req, res) => {
    var user_email = req.body.email;
    var to_address = req.body.to_address;
    var value = req.body.amount;
    let from_address = req.body.from_address;
    var web3 = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(from_address, "test", 15000);
    let BuserAccBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(from_address);
    let tran_hash = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts[1],
        to: accounts[5],
        value: web3.utils.toWei('1')
    });
    console.log("Transaction Hash:" + JSON.stringify(tran_hash));
    let AuserAccBalance = await web34.eth.getBalance(from_address);
 res.send("Balance before Tran:" + BuserAccBalance + " Balance after Tran:" + AuserAccBalance + "\nTransaction Hash is:" + tran_hash.transactionHash);

});
```

Error I am getting is :Error: "Provided address "undefined"
is invalid, the capitalization checksum test failed, or its an indrect 
IBAN address which can't be converted".

Comment: Please share your actual code and error message, not a screenshot of them. (Screenshots aren't searchable, so this question won't be useful to anyone in the future who has the same problem.)

Comment: Hey, I added my api code and error can you please check it once?

Comment: log accounts[1] and accounts[5],  Make sure these two are not ` null` and not `undefined`

Comment: What Subhod said is right. maybe your geth path is missing the jsons of the addresses that you are trying to use.

Comment: Sorry I did n't get exactly. Can u guys explain a little bit more. Thanks for u r responses

Answer (score 1):

You are Unlocking " from_address " and trying to send from accounts[1].

Try with below code

```
app.post("/sendTransaction", async (req, res) => {
    var user_email = req.body.email;
    var to_address = req.body.to_address;
    var value = req.body.amount;
    let from_address = req.body.from_address;
    var web3 = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(from_address, "test", 15000);
    let BuserAccBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(from_address);
    let tran_hash = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: from_address,
        to: accounts[5],
        value: web3.utils.toWei('1')
    });
    console.log("Transaction Hash:" + JSON.stringify(tran_hash));
    let AuserAccBalance = await web34.eth.getBalance(from_address);
 res.send("Balance before Tran:" + BuserAccBalance + " Balance after Tran:" + AuserAccBalance + "\nTransaction Hash is:" + tran_hash.transactionHash);

});
```

If still problem exists, indicate the exact line where are you getting this error. Also print all the addresses in log and update your question.

Comment: Hey, I tried the above solution but I am not getting. I am printing the accounts log.The problem is from here " await web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(from_address, "test", 15000);". I tried to print the "BuserAccBalance" but it is not printing.

Comment: I added latest screenshot also

Comment: Print from_address and try, I suspect this is not in correct format